# Frequent read/write operation from socket in C

Tags: c, sockets, server

I want to write a script for the server (socket programming) in C which will be there in listening mode and read the HTTP requests from client and do some action on that request.

For Example:
Suppose the request I got is as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><line2:connectionClearedEvent><cause>normalClearing</cause></line2:connectionClearedEvent></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I want to check, if the request has "**connectionClearedEvent**" string then increment the counter by one.

**Problem:**

**1st Idea** 
Assuming there is load on the server, if the implementation is done to write all the requests from socket to a file then due to frequent write operations, it is skipping some requests.

**Second Idea**
Assuming there is load on the server, if the implementation is to just read the incoming request and search for that keyword, then also due to frequent read operation it is skipping some request.

Can anyone suggest a way out for the same to do the above action while there is loads of request coming to server.

Edit: Code for the same
connection_handler() will handle connection for each client but the issue I am facing now is with handling file.

```html
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>    //strlen
#include<stdlib.h>    //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include<unistd.h>    //write
#include<pthread.h> //for threading , link with lpthread

//the thread function
void *connection_handler(void *);

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
 printf("Program name %s\n", argv[0]);
 if( argc == 2 )
 {
  printf("The argument supplied is %s\n", argv[1]);
 }
 else if( argc > 2 )
 {
  printf("Too many arguments supplied.\n");
 }
 else 
 {
  printf("Server Port not provided..exiting \n");
  // scanf("%s",&argv[1]);
  return 1;  
 }
 
    int socket_desc , client_sock , c , *new_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;
 
    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
 }
    puts("Socket created");
 
    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
 
    //Bind
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        //print the error message
        perror("bind failed. Error");
        return 1;
 }
    puts("bind done");
 
    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc , 3);
 
    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
 
 
    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    while( (client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)) )
    {
        puts("Connection accepted");
  
        pthread_t sniffer_thread;
        new_sock = malloc(1);
        *new_sock = client_sock;
  
        if( pthread_create( &sniffer_thread , NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) new_sock) < 0)
        {
            perror("could not create thread");
            return 1;
  }
  
        //Now join the thread , so that we dont terminate before the thread
        //pthread_join( sniffer_thread , NULL);
        puts("Handler assigned");
 }
 
    if (client_sock < 0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
 }
 
    return 0;
}

/*
 * This will handle connection for each client
* */
void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    //Get the socket descriptor
    int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
    int read_size;
    char *message , client_message[2000];
 
 static char* ok_response =
 "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
 "Content-Length: 101\r\n"
 "Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\r\n"
 "\r\n"
 "<html>\n"
 " <body>\n"
 "  <h1>Bad Request</h1>\n"
 "  <p>This server understand your request.</p>\n"
 " </body>\n"
 "</html>\n";
 
 static char* body =
 "<html>\n"
 " <body>\n"
 "  <h1>Bad Request</h1>\n"
 "  <p>This server understand your request.</p>\n"
 " </body>\n"
 "</html>\n";
 
 printf("content length : %d\n",strlen(body));
    
   //Receive a message from client
    while( (read_size = recv(sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
    {
        //Send the message back to client
  puts(client_message);
        write(sock , ok_response , strlen(ok_response));
  memset (client_message,'\0',2000);
 }
 
    if(read_size == 0)
    {
        puts("Client disconnected");
        fflush(stdout);
 }
    else if(read_size == -1)
    {
        perror("recv failed");
 }
 
    //Free the socket pointer
    free(socket_desc);
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is 'skipping some requests' how? Errors? Client errors? Server errors? Symptoms? Question? And you need to close your accepted sockets some time, instead of just leaking them.

Comment: 'new_sock = malloc(1);' too small.  Please copy your code from a site with good code.

Comment: 'fputs(client_message, fp);' use of a call that requires a NUL-terminated char array on an array that is not guaranteed NUL-terminated.

Comment: 'write(sock , ok_response , strlen(ok_response));' writes a complete response back to the client for every time recv() returns with data, even if it only returns having read just one byte.  This can result in multiple responses for one request.

Comment: 'memset (client_message,'\0',2000);' too late for the first recv() return, will not help if the buffer is loaded with the full 2000 chars by recv(), and is not necessary anyway since you have 'read_size' which will tell you where to put the NUL, (assuming a NUL is useful, ie. you will always receive data as 'text', ie. with no enbedded NULs).

Comment: @EJP Sorry for mentioning comment at wrong place. By skipping of requests I meant the client has failed to send the data to the tool as it got hanged due to loads of requests. Am I clear now?

Comment: Define 'failed to send data'. Same question. Error? Client error? Server error? Symptoms? Have you considered fixing all the bugs before jumping to conclusions?

Comment: @EJP What I can understand is when the load rises, due to server error i.e. server not able to handle any more request, the client fails to send any more requests to the server.

Comment: The client may hang, because it does not receive correctly formatted answer. Try to fix problems pointed by @MartinJames first.

Comment: You're just repeating yourself and you have still failed to answer a question you were first asked 13 hours ago. 'Fails' is not a problem description. Define 'failed to send any more requests'. What happens instead? Does it get an error? or does it just block? and if so, while sending the request? or while receiving the response. It is impossible to help you if you won't respond adequately to questions you are asked.

Answer (score 0):

There are three main things to do here (Can be combined):

1. Increase the [listening](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listen.2.html) queue (`listen(socket, <number of pending requests>)`) - This will help dealing with bursts of requests, but if your're not handling requests fast enough, this too will eventually fail
2. Distribute your workload on many [workers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool) to take advantage of modern multi-threaded and multi-processing environments. This can be done either by threads or processes where for each request, after `accept`ing the incoming connection, the new connection socket is given to a worker thread/process to handle.
   This way, you don't block the listening socket while processing the requests. This too, can only scale so much as you'll eventually run out of workers if your server is overloaded.
3. [Clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cluster) - Eventually, it's possible that a single server/machine is incapable of handling the incoming load. You'll need to create a load balancing mechanism and divert requests to different machines to process.

Comment: have added handlers for each connection using thread. Facing issue on how to effectively write it to the file.

Comment: There's no evidence here of a problem on the scale you're addressing. Merely a large number of trivial sockets programming errors.

Comment: @EJP with load of 1000 caps(requests per second), the script hangs, leading to skipping of requests. For now I have restricted printing of "client_message". which is serving as the solution for now.

Comment: @AnuragDeb I have already asked you under your question to define 'skipping of requests', and you haven't answered me. Don't post answers to comments in the wrong place.